# WLAN media streaming mode for Linux to stop ping spikes?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ping, lag

After hours of trying to fix my router ping spike problem I found a thread on Tom's Hardware. Last answers directed me to this Windows program called WLAN Optimizer:

http://www.martin-majowski.de/index.html

And it finally fixed the spikes. Problem is, i use Linux and would rather stay with Linux. The software mentioned earlier forces a "Media Streaming" mode on the Windows wireless drivers. More about it here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549314.aspx

The question is, is there an equivalent setting on Linux? I use latest Lubuntu, tried Fedora and old NetworkManager-less Debian, problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the streaming is chewing up most/all of your bandwidth, and doing it in a "spikey" way.   The solution is to implement QoS on your link - exacty how you do that depends on your link, but it might be limiting traffic to certain servers to use X% of your bandwidth.

Unfortunately implementing traffic shaping on Linux is not trivial.  Google "traffic shaping" for some guides/recipes.   Generally it involves a number of lines of custom scripts.